# Powershell Get Computer Names who are connected to the Home Directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

In AD we have Home Directory setup, and it points to a File Server which the folder it their [username]. I would like to know who is connect to those Home Directories by Computer Name by using Powershell.

I type person [username] in and it will display back which computers are connected to that folder.

I looked around in Get-ADuser but didn't find much and tried looking for commands but I could be looking it up wrong.

Thank you

[EDIT01]

I found that `Get-WmiObject Win32_serverConnection` brings back who is connected to the `HomeDirectory` using their USERNAME. The command I use is the following:

`Get-WmiObject Win32_ServerConnection -ComputerName SERVER | where username -match "USER" | where sharename -like "home" | select username, sharename, computername | sort sharename | Format-Table -AutoSize`

Which brings back a formatted table like this:

```
username sharename computername
-------- --------- ------------
USER     home      123.456.789.01
USER     home      123.456.789.02
```

Now the only problem I have is, it is not bringing back the `ComputerName` but the IP Address. I can manually nslookup and it will bring the `ComputerName` back but HOW DO I INTEGRATE that into the this command line?

[EDIT02]

What I have done is that, I push the IP Address into an Array, then have done a `foreach` using this command line:

`([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress($ipaddress)).HostName`

Which brings back the Computer Names.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Path,OU=To,OU=OrgUnit,DC=domain,DC=com" -Filter {HomeDirectory -like 'C:\*'} -Properties HomeDirectory
```

Use the `-filter` and `-Properties` parameters to include the `HomeDirectory` property. Adjust the `{HomeDirectory -like 'C:\*'}` path to your valid location, same goed for the `-SearchBase` parameter.

Comment: The above command brings information but doesn't bring back on which Computer is connected to the `HomeDirectory` I found that `Get-WmiObject Win32_ServerConnection` brings back on what I want but doesn't `nslookup` the IP.  

`Get-WmiObject Win32_ServerConnection -ComputerName FILESERVER | where username -match "USERNAME" | where sharename -like "home" | select username, sharename, computername | sort sharename | Format-Table -AutoSize`